# Integrate sonarlint in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

> Currently,I have integrated findbug with sonarqube. 
>   I want to follow sonarlint rules with sonarqube server.

Comment: If you want to configure SonarLint to use rules defined on a SonarQube server, look for "connected mode" in the simple docs at http://www.sonarlint.org/

Comment: I have done connection with Eclipse IDE but I want to follow sonarlint rules with sonarqube server.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, and what is not working for you. your question doesn't describe well your need, your target, and your blocking point.

Comment: I am using findbug rules with sonarqube server but i want to apply sonarlint rules to sonarqube sever.

Comment: SonarLint uses a default set of rules in standalone mode. In connected mode, it uses the rules defined in SonarQube. There's no such thing as "sonarlint rules".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube is compatible with PMD/Checkstyle/Findbugs.SonarLint  can run only in IDE.

Comment: SonarQube and SonarLint rely on the same implementations of the same rules from the same code analyzers.

Comment: You mean to say like if I am not using 3rd party analyzers (findBugs, checkstyle, PMD) with SonarQube then SonarQube  will follow the same rule as Sonar Lint.Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. :-)